# Using expand_dims in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to tile a length 18 1 hot vector into a 40x40 grid.

Looking at pytorch docs, expand dims seems to be what i need.

But I cannot get it to work.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
one_hot = torch.zeros(18).unsqueeze(0)
one_hot[0,1] = 1.0
one_hot
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
one_hot.expand(-1,-1,40,40)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (40) must match the existing size (18) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

I'm expecting a tensor of shape (1, 18, 40,40)

Comment: How are you mapping 18 values to the 40x40 matrix? What are the values in your expected output?

Comment: Just copying the one hot.  So each cell in the 40x40 matrix is populated with the 18 dimensional 1 hot vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) works along *singleton* dimensions of the input tensor. In your example, you are trying to `expand` a 1-by-18 tensor along its (non-existent) third and fourth dimensions - this is why you are getting an error. The only singleton dimension (=dimension with `size`==1) you have is the first dimension.

**fix**

```
one_hot = torch.zeros(1,18,1,1, dtype=torch.float)  # create the tensor with all singleton dimensions in place
one_hot[0,1,0,0] = 1.
one_hot.expand(-1,-1,40,40)
```